# Singular in $V$ regular in $HOD$

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals, inner-models

Prikry forcing can be used to produce a model $V$ of $ZFC$ such that fo rsome cardinal $\kappa$ we have:

(1) $\kappa$ is singular in $V$ of cofinality $\omega,$

(2) $\kappa$ is regular (and in fact measurable) in $HOD$.

Now my question is can this happen with $\kappa$ having uncountable cofinality in $V$. So

> **Question** Can we find a model $V$ of $ZFC$ which contains a cardinal $\kappa$ so that
>
> (1) $\kappa$ is singular of uncountable cofinality in $V$,
>
> (2) $\kappa$ is regular in $HOD$.

Let me explain why Magidor or Radin forcing do not work in general. Let's start with core model $K$ in which $\kappa$ is large enough, and let $V$ be the generic extension obtained by Magidor or Radin forcing to change the cofinality of $\kappa$ to, say, $\omega_1.$ Let $C$ be the resulting club. We can assume all elements of $C$ were regular in $K$.

**Claim.** $Lim(C) \in HOD,$ where $Lim(C)$ is the set of limit points of $C$.

**Proof.** We have $Lim(C)=\{\alpha \leq \kappa: \alpha$ is singular, but regular in $K     \} \in HOD.$

In particular $\kappa$ is  singular in $HOD$.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but this is certainly true in V=L($\mathbb{R}$)+AD. In particular, $\omega_3$ is singular in V but measurable in HOD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question is yes. In fact, it is possible to prove something stronger:

> **Theorem** (Omer Ben-Neria, Spencer Unger) Assuming the existence of suitable large cardinals, there exists a model $V$ of $ZFC$ which contains a club of cardinals all of them are regular in $HOD$ of $V$.

Their work is under preparation.

**Remark.** Their result is optimal in the sense that we can not hope to build a model in which all infinite cardinals are regular in $HOD$, as for example $\aleph_\omega$ is always singular in $HOD$.

---

**Update**: The paper by Omer Ben-Neria and Spencer Unger is now available:

> [Homogeneous changes in cofinalities with applications to HOD](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~sunger/Homogeneous.pdf)

Comment: @Rahman.M It doesn't matter. You can always manage all point in C are singular in $V$.

Comment: What are the large cardinals they're using there?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I just heard about their result by email correspondence and have not seen their paper. But I think strong type large cardinals are sufficient for it.